# Html and php email form not working

Tags: php, html

Could someone tell me what to put in a separate php file to make this html form email the results to me. I have no idea what to do. I tried to copy a php file from online. It is horrible.

```
        <form id="form_1138955" class="appnitro" method="post" action="/form/contact-form.php">
                <div class="form_description">
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
        <p></p>
    </div>                      
        <ul >

                <li id="li_1" >
    <label class="description" for="name">Name* </label>
    <span>
        <input id="name_first" name= "name_first" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="8" value=""/>
        <label>First</label>
    </span>
    <span>
        <input id="name_last" name= "name_last" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="14" value=""/>
        <label>Last</label>
    </span> 
    </li>           <li id="li_3" >
    <label class="description" for="email">Email*</label>
    <div>
        <input id="email" name="email" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div> 
    </li>       <li id="li_4" >
    <label class="description" for="phone">Phone*</label>
    <span>
        <input id="phone_123" name="phone_123" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text"> -
        <label for="phone_123">(###)</label>
    </span>
    <span>
        <input id="phone_456" name="phone_456" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text"> -
        <label for="phone_456">###</label>
    </span>
    <span>
        <input id="phone_7890" name="phone_7890" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text">
        <label for="phone_7890">####</label>
    </span>

    </li>

                <li class="buttons">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="1" />

            <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

Comment: The page doesn't have any content on it, so I don't know why you would expect it to be anything but blank.

Comment: Did you `//<-----Put Your email address here.`

Comment: If the email will send, blank page will rendered since there are no echos. The first if have `died()` function that's incorrect, should be `die()` function and it should render the message of the parameter

Comment: Unless `died` is a function they've defined. Oddly there have been a few questions lately that have a `died` function...

Comment: My eyes are full of blood seeing this code, but we must help @JustinW. with this case.

Comment: Is the php you posted on a separate page, or does the form post back to itself? I don't see a call to the mail() function. You are setting the subject, body, and to, but where do you actually send the message?

Comment: You aren't mailing or echoing anything. It's supposed to be blank....

Comment: This would throw a syntax error anyways, `died()` would not exist.

Comment: ok. im am totally confused now. Can someone just tell me what I would have to put in a separate php file to make this:

Answer (score -2):

You should put some settings like:

1. sender Email & password
2. protocol (smtp,mail,etc..)
3. Email port - [READ HERE](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)